# ItemList with QuantitativeValue for table lists

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I am trying to create a schema to use with several tables that use a list of products (e.g. bottles) arranged based on either height, volume, width, etc.

I tried this Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList" id="id1">
    <ul>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
            <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
            <span itemprop="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">        
          <span itemprop="name" class="name">Coke Bottle</span>
            <span class="measure">
                 <span itemscope  itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
                    <span itemprop="value">2359</span>
            <span itemprop="unitText">mm</span>
            <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="MMT" />
            </span> /

            <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
                    <span itemprop="value">92.52</span>
            <span itemprop="unitText">in</span>
            <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="INH" />
            </span>
            </span>
            </span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that the measure is not associated directly with the product.

How can I structure this data using Microdata to maintain the measurement values using `QuantitativeValue` and make the `ItemList` work for my need?

These are just tables showing a list of product names ordered by these values either ascending or descending, they are not used for navigation, just presenting information based on aggregated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post I see the following contradictions:

> The problem is that the measure is not associated directly with the product.

and

> These are just tables showing a list of product names

However, if this is a product, you can use the following the valid markup for your list:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ItemList" id="id1">
    <ul>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
            <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
            <span itemprop="item" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">        
          <a itemprop="url" href=example.com/list.html#cokebottle><span itemprop="name" class="name">Coke Bottle</span></a>
            <span class="measure" itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/PropertyValue">
                    <span itemprop="value">2359</span>
            <span itemprop="unitText">mm</span>
            <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="MMT" />
            <meta itemprop="propertyID" content="http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/recommendations/bkup_htm/add3lm.htm" /> /

            <span itemprop="value">92.52</span>
            <span itemprop="unitText">in</span>
            <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="INH" />
            <meta itemprop="propertyID" content="http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/recommendations/bkup_htm/add3hk.htm" />
            </span>
            </span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Here we used the **[guide of Google for Single, all-in-one-page list](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings#single-all-in-one-page-list)**:

> A single, all-in-one-page list hosts all list information, including full text of each item: for example, a gallery of recipes for various kinds of muffins, all contained on one page.

Note that the reference (s) for this markup must have the same URL, but different anchors such as **#cokebottle** in the above example. So it should be a list of all of which parts (and links to these parts) are installed on one web page.

Here we also use the type **[PropertyValue](https://schema.org/PropertyValue)** as embedded in the property **additionalProperty**. This property is part of the type **Product** so all markup is semantic relation and description for the specific product.

Also note that here we used the property **propertyID** with URL as the identifier of the value of this property.

Comment: In my application, the product image can be displayed in the comparison page loaded via AJAX call using a hash, But the site doesn't sell product nor I have a page for a specific product, it's just for specification and size comparison, can I still use the code your shared, and then what should be in the link, the URL with the hash that loaded the device in the comparison page?

Comment: Read more https://developers.google.com/search/docs/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more ++ https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174993 ++ https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-strongly-recommends-using-html-to-get-content-indexed-quickly/269841/ ++ http://www.thesempost.com/google-indexes-ranks-javascript-pages-two-waves-days-apart/ ++ http://www.thesempost.com/google-googlebot-processes-javascript-links-site/

Answer (score 1):

You can’t associate a [`QuantitativeValue`](https://schema.org/QuantitativeValue) with a `Thing`.

The best practice is to use the most specific type available. In your case, this would be [`Product`](https://schema.org/Product), or one of its sub-types, if it applies ([`IndividualProduct`](https://schema.org/IndividualProduct), [`ProductModel`](https://schema.org/ProductModel) or [`SomeProducts`](https://schema.org/SomeProducts)).

This allows you to use the properties [`depth`](https://schema.org/depth), [`height`](https://schema.org/height), [`weight`](https://schema.org/weight), and [`width`](https://schema.org/width), all of which which can take a `QuantitativeValue` value.